# Rightmost non NA column to create combined column

Tags: r

I have the following situation, with n columns (only show 3 for this example):

```
haves <- data.frame(
    x1 = c(1, 1, 1)
    , x2 = c(NA, 2, 2)
    , x3 = c(NA, NA, 3)
)

haves
  x1 x2 x3
1  1 NA NA
2  1  2 NA
3  1  2  3
```

Here the rightmost "non NA" is to be used to create a combined column like this:

```
wants <- data.frame(
    x1 = c(1, 1, 1)
    , x2 = c(NA, 2, 2)
    , x3 = c(NA, NA, 3)
    , combined = c(1,2,3)
)

wants
  x1 x2 x3 combined
1  1 NA NA        1
2  1  2 NA        2
3  1  2  3        3
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max.col` with `ties.method = 'last'` to get the column number of last non-NA value in each row. Combine it with row number and use it to subset dataframe to get the value.

```
haves$combined <- haves[cbind(seq(nrow(haves)), 
                              max.col(!is.na(haves), ties.method = 'last'))]
haves

#  x1 x2 x3 combined
#1  1 NA NA        1
#2  1  2 NA        2
#3  1  2  3        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Omit NA, get the last one:

```
apply(haves, 1, function(i) tail(na.omit(i), 1))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Or reverse coalesce using *data.table*:

```
data.table::fcoalesce(haves[, 3:1])
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rev` to reverse your *haves* and then `apply`over margin `1` and get the *first* non `NA` value.

```
haves$combined <- apply(rev(haves), 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
haves
#  x1 x2 x3 combined
#1  1 NA NA        1
#2  1  2 NA        2
#3  1  2  3        3
```